# TypeError: execute() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 7 were given

Tags: python, mysql, select, where-clause

I have the following code and it is throwing the TypeError: execute() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 7 were given. I'm not sure if it's right but here it is:

```
result_time = cur.execute("SELECT appointment_id FROM appointments WHERE appointment_time =%s", [appointment_time], "AND appointment_date =%s", [appointment_date], "AND doctor_id =%s", [actual_doctor_id.get('doctor_id')])
```

So I want a particular appointment_id when all requirements are met.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cursor.execute` takes the sql and a tuple of params - you gave the params singled-ly - hence you "overstuffed" it and get

> TypeError: execute() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 7 were given

Change your code to contain 1 sql statement and one tuple with params:

```
result_time = cur.execute(
    "SELECT appointment_id FROM appointments WHERE appointment_time = %s AND appointment_date = %s AND doctor_id = %s", 
    ( appointment_time, appointment_date, actual_doctor_id.get('doctor_id')) )
```

and it will work.

```
 cursor.execute( sql, ( param1, param2, ... ) )
 #                      this is all a tuple - hence the 2nd allowed param to execute.
```

See f.e. [mysql-documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html) or use http://bobby-tables.com/python as a quick reference.